# Import js in HTML to get model's data

Tags: javascript

I'm here again.
I have a question now, at the HTML's top, I declare a **model** which is call **showModel**
then **I import a js file to a HTML**. The code will be like:
Show.cshtml

```
@model TBS.Areas.Budget.ViewModels.showModel
//.. do something

<script src="/Scripts/jstree/circle_packing.js"></script>
```

And in the **circle_packing.js**, I want to parse JSON data.
So that I add this code at **circle_packing.js**'s top, like this:
circle_packing.js

```
var js = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Model.json)');
//.. do something
```

But web will show **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token @ in JSON at position 0**
so, how to solve this problem??
Thank u guys!:)

Comment: Your `JSON.parse` is not valid because it literally tries to parse `@Html.Raw(Model.json)` instead of some code executed to get json. Maybe wrong placement of quotes? It's not vanilla js too as I see

Answer (score 1):

Try doing it as follows

```
var js = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(@Model))');
```